# Sent ETC from Jaxx to Coinbase ETH wallet accidently

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-classic

I accidently sent ETC to an ETH wallet.
Sent ETH from Jaxx to a Coinbase ETH wallet.
ETC not appearing now on coinbase because I sent it to an ETH address.

Please can you help me with this?

I am willing to reward you for your efforts

Narendra

Comment: You will likely have to contact Coinbase support. Coinbase retains access to your wallet's private key and may be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Both Ethereum Classic(ETC) & Ethereum(ETH) use the same format for their key pairs.

If you can **export your private key** belonging to the ETH account that you sent the ETC to, then you can **import it into an ETC wallet** to access your funds. This works vice versa also.

The slightly less promising news is that coinbase will not make private keys accessible. It would prevent them from taking advantage of the [secure cold-storage technology to protect your funds](https://support.coinbase.com/customer/portal/articles/1526452-where-can-i-find-the-private-keys-for-my-wallet-).

You've two options, wait until they start to support ETC, (I'm not sure what their plans are for this.) or contact their customer support to see if they can arrange something for you.

Best of luck with this. Hope it works out and you get your ETC back!