# Sent ETC to ETH and need to know how to recover please!

Tags: ether, ethereum-classic

I traded ETC from project.github.io/etherwallet to ETH at BTC-e and didn't realise the difference in blockchains.

How can I access this? I did this in June.
All help appreciated.
I have the API keys in WEX.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sent ETC from Jaxx to Coinbase ETH wallet accidently](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29962/sent-etc-from-jaxx-to-coinbase-eth-wallet-accidently)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sent transaction between ETH and ETC accounts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23759/sent-transaction-between-eth-and-etc-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it they have the same format for private keys and addresses. I believe My Ether Wallet works with both chains. If you import your private key from etherwallet to MEW you *should* be able to access it.